# Show that the sum equals $0$ according to Cesàro

Tags: fourier-analysis, cesaro-summable

I'm stuck at some problems in my Fourier Analys course, maybe you got a clue.

If $x \neq n \cdot 2 \pi$, then

$$
\frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx) = 0, \quad (C,1).
$$

Solution:

So I know where I want to go and there is only one step I fail with when I peak at the solution manual, here we go

$$
\frac{1}{2}+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx) = 0 \Leftrightarrow 1+ 2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx) = 0
$$

Now  rewrite $\cos(kx)= \frac{1}{2}(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx})$ and we have that

$$
1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}) = 0
$$

and now the solution manual shows that the sum equals $-1$ and we are done, anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown in [Nicolas' answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603391/show-that-the-sum-equals-0-according-to-ces%C3%A0ro/1603459#1603459), the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)$ is given by

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\cos(kx)=\frac{\cos(nx)-\cos((n+1)x)}{2(1-\cos(x))}-\frac12,\qquad x\neq 2\pi l\tag{1}$$

The Cesaro sum is

$$\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{n=1}^m\left[\frac{\cos(nx)-\cos((n+1)x)}{2(1-\cos(x))}-\frac12\right]=\\=\lim_{m\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{m}\frac{\cos(x)-\cos((m+1)x)}{2(1-\cos(x))}-\frac12=-\frac12$$

Comment: Thank you for the conclusion! +1

Answer (score 1):

You are on the good track.

$$1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}) = 1+ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{ikx}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e^{-ikx}$$ Now, $$e^{ikx}=\big(e^{ix}\big)^k$$ $$e^{-ikx}=\big(e^{-ix}\big)^k$$ So, two geometric series, isn't it ?

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: But with $r=e^{ix}$ we have $|r|=1$, so the series doesn't converge in the conventional sense. Only for $|r|<1$ can we use the standard formula for the geometric series $s=1/(1-r)$.

Comment: Oh right! Now I made it! :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT :** This post is not a full answer, the conclusion is given in Matt L.'s post.

Let us compute
\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathrm{e}^{ikx}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-ikx} & = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathrm{e}^{ikx}-1+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\mathrm{e}^{-ikx}-1 \\ & = \frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{i(n+1)x}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{ix}}-1+\frac{1-\mathrm{e}^{-i(n+1)x}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}}-1 \\
 & = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{i(n+1)x}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{ix}}+\frac{\mathrm{e}^{-ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-i(n+1)x}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}} \\
& = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{ix}-\mathrm{e}^{i(n+1)x}-1+\mathrm{e}^{inx}+\mathrm{e}^{-ix}-\mathrm{e}^{-i(n+1)x}-1+\mathrm{e}^{-inx}}{1-\mathrm{e}^{ix}+1-\mathrm{e}^{-ix}} \\
& = \frac{2\left(-1+\cos(x)+\cos(nx)-\cos((n+1)x)\right)}{2\left(1-\cos(x)\right)} \\
& = -1+\frac{\cos(nx)-\cos((n+1)x)}{1-\cos(x)}.
\end{align}

Comment: This is not correct. If you removed the "$\frac12$ +" from the parenthesis of the left-hand side of your last equation, the result would also be zero, which means you would have proved that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx)=0$. In the same way you could "prove" $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx)=A$ for arbitrary constants $A$. The problem is that what you did is no Cesaro summation.

Comment: @MattL. I am not sure to see where you disagree : I did not remove any term at the end, I have factorized the term $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, but I suggested that you remove the term $\frac12 + \ldots$ and see what the result would be. It would still be zero, which means that your prove is flawed, because if the limit is zero *without* that term, you would have proved that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\cos(kx)=0$.

Comment: @MattL. I see what you mean now. Indeed, in this way, we have that $A+\sum\cos(kx)$ is $0$ in Cesaro sense. But is the definition of Cesaro summation incorrect ?

Comment: Yes, what you calculated is the limit of $\frac{1}{n}s_n$ where $s_n$ is the partial sum. What you need to compute is the limit of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}s_n$, i.e. the limit of the average value of the partial sums.

Comment: @MattL. Oh good point here! I forgot the $n$ factor (which is important, indeed). I will try to fix it as soon as possible. Thanks you!

Comment: I removed the final part which was not the good definition of the Cesaro summation.